# Shopify - custom price for each customer, calculate with external api

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I would like to sell a few products on Shopify. The user should be able to select a product and fill a form. Then some of these values will be passed to an external API and the API returns the correct price. How to implement this in Shopify? Are there any Shopify apps that could support the development of this?

The development process has not yet begun, so I'm free to use any other shop builder out there.

Answer (score 0):

There are some apps to make it possible so you can sell at different price for customers.

[Shopify appstore app](https://apps.shopify.com/wholesale-club?utm_campaign=Guru%20Ask&utm_medium=Forum&utm_source=social)

[Bold custom pricing](https://apps.shopify.com/customer-pricing?utm_campaign=Guru+Ask&utm_medium=Forum&utm_source=social)

[Wholesale pricing discount](https://apps.shopify.com/wholesale-pricing-discount?utm_campaign=Guru%20Ask&utm_medium=Forum&utm_source=social)

But I don't think these apps will not perfectly satisfy your needs.

If I can suggest something, after customer fills a form and get a price, then you can make price of product show on the store, and at the same time you can make a request to change the price of that product by using Shopify product api. Then everytime customer comes to your store and buy products, the price will change and they will be able to purchage at different price. I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided to use [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/en-de/payments/checkout) for this. The design is amazing and the setup is simple. Later I will most likely switch to Stripe.js and [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/en-de/payments/elements) to enable even more customization.